# subquery in select statement vs subquery in FROM statement

Tags: mysql, sql, relation

So If I define a table in FROM with a subquery, the subquery can be just about anything:

```
FROM (SELECT x FROM table)
```

But If i want to use a subquery in the SELECT Clause, it seems to have more restrictions for example

```
SELECT (SELECT x FROM table) AS x
```

Can raise the error

> Sub query returns more than 1 row

if there are multiple rows.

Why can't a sub query in the SELECT clause have a single column and multiple rows? And if it can't accept multiple rows, why can't I use something like MAX() to aggregate the rows into one value?

For example, query (1) works and (2) does not.

Query 1:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT salary FROM Employee 
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1) AS salary;
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT
    MAX(SELECT salary FROM Employee) AS salary;
```

Comment: Because SQL statements have predefined structure. They're not a free text from which the DBMS need to guess your expectations. What does it need to do with multiple rows in `SELECT` list? SQL result set is in 1NF

Comment: The first one is a "table expression" (aka derived table, or inline view) that can have any cardinality (number of rows) and any degree (number of columns). The second one is a "scalar subquery" that is limited to cardinality 0 or 1, and always has degree 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL supports various types of subqueries.  A very important distinction is between:

- *derived tables* which are subqueries in the `FROM` clause that return a result set that can have multiple rows and multiple columns.
- *scalar subqueries* which return (in general) one column and up to one row.

What you are describing as a "subquery in the `SELECT` clause is a scalar subquery.  The value is a replacement for a literal value, so it can only return one column.  If the scalar returns zero rows, then the value is `NULL`.

Note that scalar subqueries are sometimes extended to support multiple columns.  In that case, the return value is really a *tuple*, so the value is still "one thing".  But that thing can have multiple fields like a struct or record many programming languages.

Answer (score 2):

You may include a subquery as a SELECT expression as long as it returns only at much ONE value. Why? Because the SELECT clause defines how are calculated the values of EACH ROW of the returned row set.

So, the query nº2 would be right, but it should be written like this:

```
SELECT (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM Employee) AS salary;
```